# chain fadeIn, fadeOut and asynchronous animate() function

Tags: jquery

This code seems to work fine, fortunately, as it seems to me easy to use and to understand:

```
.red {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
}

<font id="test" size="7">0000000000000000</font>

$('#test').fadeOut(500, function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $this.text('11111111111111111111')
  .fadeIn(500)
  .fadeOut(500, () => {
    $this.text('2222222222222222');
    $this.css("color", "green").addClass("red")
  })
  .fadeIn(500)
  .delay(500)
  .animate({
      'margin-left': '250px'
    }, {
      duration: 3000
  })
  .delay(1000)
  .fadeOut(500)
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cwustkr/1/

However, I don't understand why it works. Isn't animate() asynchonous? Why is everything executed in correct order, even when the last delay() and fadeOut() functions are chained to animate() and not put in as callback functions of animate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's exactly what the `delay` method [is intended to do](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

It's a jQuery-specific method, one that allows chained jQuery calls to be delayed. While you could *also* come up with a method that achives the same thing by putting later functions into callbacks of `fade` and `animate`, it would get ugly if you have many such fades and animations.

Here's an example of a possible asynchronous chained queue that has the same behavior you're interested in:

```js
class Class {
  doSomething(fn) {
    const inst = this instanceof Child ? this : new Child();
    inst.queue.push(fn);
    if (!(this instanceof Child)) {
      inst.nextInQueue();
    }
    return inst;
  }
}
class Child extends Class {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.queue = [];
  }
  nextInQueue() {
    if (this.queue.length) {
      const nextFn = this.queue.shift();
      Promise.resolve(nextFn())
        .then(() => this.nextInQueue());
    }
  }
  delay(ms) {
    this.queue.push(() => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)));
    return this;
  }
}

const c = new Class();
c
  .doSomething(() => console.log('something 1!'))
  .doSomething(() => console.log('something 2!'))
  .delay(1000)
  .doSomething(() => console.log('something 3'))
```

Comment: but how does the last delay (".delay(1000)") know, when animate(...) is ready so it can start? Sorry if I am not understanding certain concepts here.

Comment: When `animate` or `fadeIn` is called, jQuery can set an internal event that triggers when the animation/fade is done, and then it can call the next item in the chained queue (if any) - you can see a native implementation in such a queue in the edit